# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error create table in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1

I have this code :

```
try{
   $aws = $this->getContainer()->get(Service::class);
   $query = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS newtable;CREATE TABLE newtable LIKE actions;';
   $aws->executeQuery($query);
}catch (\Exception $exception){
  $output->writeln("Can't create new tables, with message :");
  $output->writeln(sprintf("%s", $exception->getMessage()));
}
```

And the Service class function `executeQuery` :

```
public function executeQuery($query, $multiple = true, $fetch = true)
{
    $res = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    $result = $res->execute();

    return ($fetch) ? ($multiple ? $res->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) : $res->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) : $result;
}
```

The table is created but I get the error message : 
`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error`. I don't understand what is the problem that drop this error. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Symfony use Doctrine, no? Look this question, maybe related to what you want : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041484/mysql-with-symfony2

Comment: @Mickael Leger It's not a must to use Doctrine however it's suggested

Comment: `General error `, can u provide more info ? It looks like u have problem with connection with your DB, are u sure everything is OK with connection ? Try some simple query ?

Comment: As I said the table is created, so the connection is good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use fetch nor fetchAll on the statements that do not return the data like update/insert/drop/create table

That may be the problem.

Changing

```
$aws->executeQuery($query);
```

to

```
$aws->executeQuery($query, false, false );
```

should help because therefore only the result of `$res->execute()` will be returned.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. Thank you